# Does vendor.bundle.js contain libraries imported inside lazy loaded modules?

Tags: javascript, angular

Or it only contains libraries imported inside AppModule? I deleted everything from app.module.ts and the size of vendor.bundle.js is 9.5MB when using ng serve and 3.22MB when using ng build

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Is something preventing you from opening the file, and looking at the contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does vendor.bundle.js contain libraries imported inside lazy loaded modules?

Yes, anything classified as a vendor library goes into the vendor bundle.

> Or it only contains libraries imported inside AppModule

No, but you can find blog posts dating back to Angular 2 (when it was first released) that state *AppModule* controlled the vendor bundle. A lot has changed since then.

In Angular 5, you could create a `src/vendor.ts` file that allowed you to *import* the modules you wanted to place into the vendor bundle. Support for this feature was removed in Angular 6 (at least I think it was, but I have never used it).

In Angular 6, things are far more automated.

> the size of vendor.bundle.js is 9.5MB when using ng serve and 3.22MB when using ng build.

There is no *tree shaking* and *optimization* performed when you run `ng server` by default. You should only be concerned about bundle sizes after you do a *production* build.

Also, you should not be using `ng server` as a production web server.

### Webpack Bundle Analyzer

I recommend you give the bundle analyzer a try. It's the best way to inspect bundles to see what is inside, and compare the difference between development and production builds.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer